# run C++ compiler via batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to start learning C so started reading "C for dummies". It asked me to create a batch file that runs the gcc command that runs the compiler (Dev-C++). 
I managed to create a gcc.bat file in c:\windows using the command "copy con gcc.bat". In this file I inserted the path name and details as in the book using the terminal, which is "@c:\Dev-C++\bin\gcc %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6"
(I made sure the pathname is similar to the path in which Dev-C++ is installed)

Now to check if it is installed properly I went to another folder and typed "gcc -v",
however it returns "the system cannot find the path specified".

Can you help me what I did wrong?

Many thanks :)

Comment: You already know the path to GCC, so use it like this, `@"C:\Dev-C++\bin\gcc" -v`. Alternatively, change directory to `"C:\Dev-C++\bin"`, or add it to your `%PATH%` location and use it directly.

Comment: If you are on Windows the DOS tag is *inappropriate*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev-C++ is old. I used it myself many years ago, but then I discovered Code::Blocks (http://codeblocks.org/) which I still use today.

As for gcc running in the Command Prompt, you could just run this as the first command:

```
SET PATH=C:\Dev-C++\bin;%PATH%
```

After that you can just run gcc in the prompt.

A more recent version of GCC for Windows is available at http://winlibs.com/. Instructions on how to use it from console and Code::Blocks are on the website.